# Flutter removing File from a List is not working

Tags: flutter, list, dart

in my flutter app i'm adding a File to my empty list,

```
widget.selectedAssets.value = List.from(widget.selectedAssets.value)..add(file);
```

but before this i'm checking if the data exists before adding to it. if the data exists i'll remove it.

```
final exists =
                        List.from(widget.selectedAssets.value).contains(file);

                    if (exists) {
                      widget.selectedAssets
                          .value = List.from(widget.selectedAssets.value)..remove(file);
                        // ..removeWhere(
                        //     (element) => element.toString() == file.toString());
                    } else {
                      widget.selectedAssets.value =
                          List.from(widget.selectedAssets.value)..add(file);
                    }
```

but removing is not working. why is that?. the list is coming from another stateful class with Value Notifier.

Comment: what is the `runType` of this variable `widget.selectedAssets.value` ? if its an object , probably thats the problem. because comparing object in dartlang is need to specifiec.

Comment: Can you add a full code? `widget.selectedAssets.value = List.from(widget.selectedAssets.value)..add(file);` this looks like it does nothing. It's basically `List[file] = List[file]`. The List.from method creates a list but I'm assuming that selectedAssets is already a list? And you're telling that value from selectedAssets is now another list?

Comment: the type of the `widget.selectedAsset` is of type `ValueNotifier<List<File?>>` then when in use with the value it returns `List<File?>` . and the file is `File?`. i used the same method without the `Value Notifier` it worked. but now it's not working

Comment: @Piotr i added it in the previous comment.

Comment: First of all check if the "exists" variable is returning true when it should. If not, your issue is with the File comparison.

Comment: @DanielPossamai it doesn't even execute on tap func when i try to remove, but it works when i try to add

Comment: If it doesn't even execute on tap function, probably the issue is with tap function itself.

Comment: @DanielPossamai i used the tap function for the add functionality, it works

Comment: I would suggest you to add full code, so we could better understand the issue.